# Why does touch bar sometimes ignore first touch?

Tags: macos, touch-bar

Every once in awhile the touch bar registers, reacts by highlighting the virtual button pressed, but ignores the actual button press on my touch bar. This is most noticeable on the lock screen button I’ve added.

Touching it a second time always works fine, as if the touch bar has now gotten focus.

Has anyone else experienced this, fixed it, or been able to reproduce it consistently enough to file a bug report?

Comment: I don't recall ever having this issue. Have you updated to the latest OS and restarted your computer?

Comment: Of course. I’ve had it on multiple machines. Perhaps it’s a developer specific app that causes it?

Comment: I doubt one app could affect touch bar behavior across the OS. But I suppose I could see there being issues when using touch bar with one specific app.

Comment: It’s definitely macOS buttons only — volume and lock is ones I’ve noticed now that I’m paying a bit more attention. After I unlock laptop or after I’m using an app for awhile. Have not been able to reproduce sans using something else for awhile, hence the “focus” hypothesis.

Comment: Err, might be other buttons, too. I have just only noticed it on macOS ones. Perhaps it's an especially quick / light touch? The button animation is definitely triggered, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**This has been an issue since precisely macOS High Sierra beta 3.** In the release notes for this pre-release update<sup>1</sup>, **‘heuristics’ were updated** with regard to preventing accidental Touch Bar inputs.

Since that update, pressing the Touch Bar too soon after another keyboard input too close to the Touch Bar will invalidate the Touch Bar press. The key will illuminate but only very briefly and the input will not pass. It is then necessary to press the key again for it to go through. Notice the difference between q-esc and 1-esc.

[image: Touch Bar key invalidation demonstration video]

According to event viewer I observed while recording that video,

- 4 of the 5 q-esc presses passed through the esc
  (the last press I slightly missed the activation area of esc, which was something else mentioned in the release notes: the activation areas were reduced in from the edges), and
- 0 out of 5 1-esc presses passed through the esc.

I installed macOS updates on my external disk first and I could instantly replicate this issue when using beta 3 and had no problem with beta 2.

**I filed a radar** per the instructions given in the release notes for anyone who had feedback for this change, with my view of the problem this change made for people who are more accurate with their Touch Bar key presses. Unfortunately, this radar was closed as **won't be fixed**.

It is my impression this delay is a feature: part of the remedy for people who provide spurious inputs to the Touch Bar, which was something complained about constantly on virtually all the reviews I read and watched, yet not something I've ever experienced myself.

<sup>1</sup> Even though High Sierra is released, I am unsure as to whether the release notes for pre-release versions of macOS can be reproduced here for those who are not part of the developer programme.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like I'm hitting a bug in whatever logic is doing this. I'm definitely not hitting the touchpad at the same time as another key, but it's often a side-hit with a partial swipe as I walk away and lock the computer. Unfortunate, as I like just about everything else about the TouchBar a ton.

Comment: So Apple won't change this, but is there any hack or way around it? Nothing at all?

Comment: Hopefully there is an answer. I asked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/421490/290197)