# Force MacBook Pro Touch Bar to register all inputs?

Tags: macbook-pro, settings, touch-bar, input-source

The Touch Bar is programmed to [ignore what it believes to be erroneous inputs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320639/290197).

Is there a way to reprogram or override this behaviour (via settings or via coding hacks) to ensure that inputs are registered?